# jh_captcha throws "Validation failed while trying to call showAction"

Tags: typo3, extbase, recaptcha

I've implemented jh_captcha into my extension as descripted in the documentation:

https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/extensions/jh_captcha/Developer/Index.html#add-the-captcha-to-your-domain-model

It's working create within Actions like New, Edit or List. But I get the following error as soon `showAction` is called:

```
Validation failed while trying to call showAction
```

As soon as I remove `NotEmpty` from the validation the showActions are working, but New and Edit obviously not.

Comment: Maybe you can add your implementation as a source code snippet to let us see what you did so far.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Possibly the validation fails on subobjects. There is also a solution to remove or change Validators inside the initializeXY Actions. Heres a german blog post about this topic: http://blog.teamgeist-medien.de/2016/02/typo3-extbase-validierung-von-unterobjekten-deaktivieren.html

Answer (score 0):

You can add the annotation `@dontvalidate $param` on your showAction so the validation is not proceeded.